# Eloquent ORM query

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-7, eloquent-relationship

I currently have an Eloquent ORM query.

```
$uploadedSC = SC::select('id')->with(['cont'=> function ($q) {
    return $q->with('crs:id,title')->select('*');
}])->where('act', true)->get();
```

But I wanna add a `->where('act',true)` query to my `crs` table. However, it gives an error. How can I write this query?

```
$uploadedSC = SC::select('id')->with(['cont'=> function ($q) {
    return $q->with('crs:id,title')->where('act',true)->select('*');
}])->where('act', true)->get();
```

Comment: Can you add the error?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$uploadedSC = SC::select('id')
    ->with(['cont.crs:id,title' => function ($crs) {
        $crs->where('act', true);
    }])
    ->where('act', true)
    ->get();
```

Depending on the direction of the relationship you must select the foreign key of `cont` in `crs` or you will receive an error. This is the problem of giving bad names to your models and tables, other programmers will not understand at the first time what you are trying to do.